# Problem with Sorting Excel via Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, ms-access-2016

I try to sort data in an Excel sheet with VBA in Access. I tried several solutions found either here on StackOverflow or elsewhere but no matter what - I always run into either one of two errors.

The most basic code was:

```
Set theSheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
theSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
theSheet.Range("A1:R71").sort key1:=Range("M2"), order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes
```

There Access throws me the error that the sub or function is not defined and marks *Range* as the culprit. So I add `theSheet.`:

```
Set theSheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
theSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
theSheet.Range("A1:R71").sort key1:=theSheet.Range("M2"), order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes
```

Now Access states that the Sort method of the Range object could not be executed.

And no matter how I write the code - I keep oscillating between those two error messages.

Among the variations tried:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Range( _
     "M2:M71"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
     xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Sort
    .SetRange ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung").Range("A1:R71")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

…both with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Auswertung")` or `myWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` or `theSheet`, with our without DataOption or SortOn, etc.

I always get an error.

I also recorded a macro in Excel doing exactly what I wanted to do and copied the code from Excel to Access (also tried some changes) but couldn’t get it done.

I’m running out of ideas and code snippets to try.
By the way, I’d prefer to use `Range(theSheet.Cells(1, 1), theSheet.Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))` instead of `Range("A1:R71")`.

Any ideas why it is not working?

In case it might be important: I use Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 running on Windows Server 2016 Standard.

Comment: Two things to check: 1) VBE - Tools - References: Is Microsoft Excel <ver no> checked here? 2) Add a `Dim theSheet as Excel.Worksheet`. It won't help but it will show you a better error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

As for 1) - where do I find that? My Access is in German. And there’s no "Tools" or something similar.
As for 2) - I already did. But maybe there’s the catch: I could not Dim as Excel.Worksheet only as Object.

Comment: In the Visual Basic Editor (VBE)

Comment: "Visual Basic For Applications", "Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library", "OLE Automation", "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" and "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" are checked. (In case another German user is looking for this: Extras > Verweise…)

Comment: I should work with those references checked. Try in a clean database with a minimum of code.